# Adding new row glitch in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the following code that adds a new line to a range of rows within a section in a spreadsheet. As there are several of these sections, sBudgetLine is passed in as the start value of the range (Section name) which is added with an extra 1 to miss the headers of the section (date, description and price).

All works fine, however when the row is added occasionally the formatting that I have hard coded doesn't work and adds an extra line further down the page as well as the new row which is in the right place.

```
Sub AddNewAllocToSpendLine(sBudgetLine As String, Optional sSheetName As String = c_Alloc2SpendSheetName)

Dim c As Range
Dim N As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim formula As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Worksheets(sSheetName)

    Set c = .Columns(1).Find(sBudgetLine, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not (c Is Nothing) Then

        lastRow = .Cells(c.Row, 2).End(xlDown).Row

        Worksheets(sSheetName).Activate
        Worksheets(sSheetName).Range("B" & lastRow + 1, "E" & lastRow + 1).Activate

        Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Selection.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row, "E" & ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        With Selection.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row, "D" & ActiveCell.Row).Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With

        Selection.Cells(1, 4).formula = "=IF(" & "D" & ActiveCell.Row & "="""","""",IF(" & "D" & ActiveCell.Row & ">14999.99,""Minimum 3 formal competitive tenders - inform PSU"",IF(" & "D" & ActiveCell.Row & ">2499.99,""Minimum 3 written quotes based on written specification"",IF(" & "D" & ActiveCell.Row & ">999.99,""Minimum 3 written quotes"",IF(" & "D" & ActiveCell.Row & ">499.99,""Minimum 3 oral quotes"",IF(" & "D" & ActiveCell.Row & ">249.99,""One written or verbal quote"",""One written or verbal quote""))))))"

    End If
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried all sorts and can't figure whats wrong, could this be a vba glitch? If this is the case, is there a better way of providing the formatting with the added row?

Answer (score 1):

You started off with a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) referencing the parent worksheet then seemed to abandon it. If a larger block of cells encompassing the cells you want to [.Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) is already the [.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) then the selection does not change, only the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx).

Best to avoid using the [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) method and [Range .Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) method altogether¹.

```
Sub AddNewAllocToSpendLine(sBudgetLine As String, Optional sSheetName As String = c_Alloc2SpendSheetName)

    Dim rw As Variant, nr As Long

    With Worksheets(sSheetName)
        rw = Application.Match(sBudgetLine, .Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(rw) Then
            nr = .Cells(rw, "B").End(xlDown).Row + 1
            .Rows(nr).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            With .Range(.Cells(nr, "B"), .Cells(nr, "E"))
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                With .Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                    .ColorIndex = 1
                End With
                .Cells(1, 4).formula = _
                    "=IF(D" & nr & "=TEXT(,), TEXT(,), " & _
                     "IF(D" & nr & ">14999.99, ""Minimum 3 formal competitive tenders - inform PSU"", " & _
                     "IF(D" & nr & ">2499.99, ""Minimum 3 written quotes based on written specification"", " & _
                     "IF(D" & nr & ">999.99, ""Minimum 3 written quotes"", " & _
                     "IF(D" & nr & ">499.99, ""Minimum 3 oral quotes"", " & _
                     "IF(D" & nr & ">249.99, ""One written or verbal quote"", " & _
                        """One written or verbal quote""))))))"
            End With
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

`TEXT(,)` is just a way of writing `""` without having to write it as `""""` in a string.

---

.¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. I'm new to VBA coming from C# so its a minefield of understanding the syntax!